# Get the user ID inside a custom middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm creating a middleware that based on a cookie makes an operation ... But for that I need the id of the logged user.

Is this possible in InvokeAsync?

Answer (score 1):

Custom middleware has the `InvokeAsync` method which has a `HttpContext` parameter.

`HttpContext` has a `User` property which gives information on the current user context.

```cs
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    var userIdentity = context.User.Identity;
    var uName = userIdentity.Name;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code sample :

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var userIdentity = context.User.Claims.Where(x=>x.Type==ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault().Value;
    // Do work that doesn't write to the Response.
    await next.Invoke();
    // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
});
```

Comment: Not Working  :-(

Comment: You should make sure the middleware fires after authentication middleware , and what do you mean by not working ?